# Why is the "wrong" definition of intersection of varieties the "right" one for generalized Bézout?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, projective-varieties

For ease of notation, define the degree of a variety to be the sum of the degrees of its irreducible components. The generalized Bézout theorem (due to Fulton and Macpherson) states that, for $V_1$, $V_2$ varieties in $\mathbb{A}^n$ or $\mathbb{P}^n$,
$$\deg(V_1\cap V_2) \leq \deg(V_1) \deg(V_2).$$
See section 8.4 in Fulton's Intersection Theory (or II.3.2.2 in Danilov-Shokurov, say).

Here $V_1\cap V_2$ just means the variety whose set of points over an algebraically closed field $K$ is $V_1(K)\cap V_2(K)$. There are ways of assigning multiplicities to the components of $V_1\cap V_2$ so that the inequality above is an equality, but let us not get into that.

I was recently having lunch and tea (involving donuts of the wrong genus) with two algebraic geometers visiting Uganda. I was talking to them about some things that directly follow from the above, and one of them that they could not possibly be right without additional conditions. When I showed them the statement above, they expressed surprise that such a thing could be true without qualifications.

It turned out that we were having a bit of a communication difficulty (not helped by my not being an algebraic geometer; they had to explain to me what "Cohen-Macaulay" means - if you assume that condition, everybody agrees). Here is an example they gave me. Bottom line: if by $V_1\cap V_2$ you mean what I said before (let us call this the "naïve" definition), then everything works out -- the statement of the generalized Bézout theorem is true; however, if you interpret $V_1\cap V_2$ as they do (apparently the "right" definition), the statement of the theorem is not true.

**Example.** Let us work in $\mathbb{A}^4$. Let $V_1$ be the union of the xy-plane through the origin and the zw-plane through the origin. Let $V_2$ be the hyperplane given by $x=z$. Then, using the naïve definition, we see that $V_1\cap V_2$ is the union of the line $x=z=w=0$ and the line $x=y=z=0$. So all is well: $\deg(V_1\cap V_2)=2$, $\deg(V_1)=2$, $\deg(V_2)=1$.

However, the "right" definition involves working with the ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$ defining $V_1$ and $V_2$ (namely, $I_1=(x z, x w, y z, y w)$ and $I_2=(x-z)$)
and taking the sum $I_1+I_2$ (which here equals $(x z, x w, y z, y w, x-z)$). I can reply that I also do that: what I understand by $V_1\cap V_2$ is just the variety defined by $I_1+ I_2$, or, what is the same (or so I thought), by the radical of $I_1+ I_2$.

But no, they were not happy with that: taking the radical destroys information. It took me a bit of time to understand that they were telling me that the right thing to do was to take the primary decomposition of $I_1+ I_2$, and define $V_1\cap V_2$ to consist of one component for each ideal in the primary decomposition.

Even I can figure out that $I_1\cap I_2$ has primary decomposition $Q_1\cap Q_2\cap Q_3$, where $$Q_1=(x,y,z),\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; Q_2 = (x,z,w),\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
Q_3 = (x-z,y,z^2,w).$$
Here $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ just give us the lines $x=z=w=0$ and the line $x=y=z=0$,
whereas $Q_3$ is a slightly fattened-up version of the point at the origin (its radical is $(x,y,z,w)$, which defines the point at the origin). So, the degree of $V_1\cap V_2$ would have to be $3$ (or greater than $3$, if you somehow defined a fat point to have degree greater than $1$; this is just a stray thought on my part) and so the generalized Bézout theorem would not hold.

*End of example.*

Now, I am not too bothered, since, for my applications, the naïve definition of intersection is completely appropriate; it seems I can just go on working as before. Still, I am a bit bothered: how come one gets an elegant, useful, very general inequality if one uses the "wrong" (naïve) definition, and one has to assume additional conditions (which are a pain to check, as they are not inherited by unions) if one wants the same inequality for the "right" definition of $V_1\cap V_2$? Also, why is the "right" definition the right one, and the naïve one naïve? Or is it just two definitions that are appropriate for different purposes?

PS. What is the better name for the "naïve" intersection: "set-theoretic intersection" or "geometric intersection"? The algebraic geometers in this (true) story called the "right" definition "ideal-theoretic"; as I said above, the naïve definition looks ideal-theoretic to me as well - one just needs to take the radical before decomposing, no?

Comment: The fundamental idea of intersection theory is to define an intersection product that preserves rational equivalence. Take a doubled line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and intersect it with a general reduced line. Then in your definition the intersection is one point, but it should be two points because you could replace the double line with some smooth conic up to rational equivalence. I think set-theoretic intersection is reasonable terminology for your notion. I guess one may object that the doubled line isn't a variety!

Comment: @SamirCanning Right, it isn't a variety. What would be an example with varieties?

The funny thing is that the generalization of Bézout's theorem I've quoted comes from Intersection theory; I gather from a paper by Vogel that it definitely wasn't known before Fulton and Macpherson.

Comment: You can just do the same example, replacing the doubled line with the smooth conic that is tangent to a line, and then move the line to a different line via a rational equivalence that intersects the conic transversely. If the goal of intersection theory is "to define an intersection product that preserves rational equivalence" then one does it as in Fulton's book. If the goal is just to have this version of Bézout then you could set it up in the way you described.

Comment: Preserving rational equivalence is not needed for what I am doing; having a clean inequality is far more important. One can use this version of Bézout (which comes from Fulton's book) to prove that the degree of the preimage $f^{-1}(V)$ of a variety can be bounded nicely given bounds on $\deg(V)$ and on the degree of the polynomials defining the morphism $f$, for instance. Those bounds would not hold if one defined $f^{-1}(V)$ ideal-theoretically rather than set-theoretically. (I am still not completely happy with "set-theoretic" here; these are still varieties and ideals, not just sets.)

Comment: It seems like the ideal-theoretic version is what I would call scheme-theoretic, and what you are doing is taking the induced reduced subscheme structure on the intersection. You could call it the reduced intersection.

Comment: One question (so that I am sure that I understand all this correctly). Theorem 1.1 of "3264 and all that" of Eisenbud and Harris gives a general form of Bézout's theorem as an equality (with components of the intersection being counted with multiplicity), assuming that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are of complementary dimensions. Is it understood there that the components of $V_1\cap V_2$ are the components of the reduced intersection? Or is it the case that, if the dimensions are complementary, then examples such as the above (where Bézout doesn't hold even as an inequality) cannot exist?

Comment: That theorem is about an intersection product in the Chow ring under the assumption that the subvarieties intersect in the correct codimension. The elements of the Chow ring are formal linear combinations of subvarieties (emphasis on variety) modulo rational equivalence, so the terms inside the brackets are understood to be with the reduced structure, and the multiplicities coming from non-reducedness are recorded as coefficients. It is not true in general that $[V_1\cap V_2]=[V_1]\cdot[V_2]$ in the Chow ring (this is where your Cohen-Macaulay discussion comes into play).

Comment: Right, sorry; the assumption is that the intersection is of the "correct" codimension, not that the dimensions are complementary.

Comment: To me, it is still funny that the version of Bézout's theorem as a general inequality for the reduced intersection is not better known (or is it really very well-known, as I used to assume?). It's clean and tremendously useful.

Comment: I think the last non-postscript line of your question has it right: It is just two definitions that are appropriate for different purposes.  Maybe it is helpful to say that

(1) Very often when one applies intersection theory in algebraic geometry, the goal is really to understand a tensor product or pushforward of coherent sheaves, rather than any kind of variety directly, so of course one needs a statement that keeps track of the sheaf.

Comment: (2) It is a relatively common experience to have access to a theorem that computes some intersection set-theoretically but not be able to proceed to the next step of the argument because one needs to know the actual ideal. So theorems computing invariants that distinguish an ideal from its radical are often useful. No matter how elegant the degree-bounding statement is, it's not very useful within algebraic geometry (I don't off the top of my head know any applications of it, maybe there are some) despite being very useful in various applications of algebraic geometry.

Comment: So there do just happen to be different statements, each elegant in its own way, that are useful in different scenarios. (And I concur with Samir that it should certainly be called "set-theoretic intersection", which is exactly the common terminology in algebraic geometry for this kind of thing.)

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks. Incidentally, what other applications of the set-theoretical bound do you know? I know it's very useful to *me*. In general I can see that it should be useful whenever you are counting points on varieties, say.

Comment: Actually, what you call the "right" definition has no real applications in algebraic geometry (as far as I know) without the Cohen--Macaulay condition, even though it is natural from the point of view of commutative algebra.

Comment: @naf I'd appreciate if you said "what you call the ""right"" definition", with double quotation marks, since it's not what's right from my perspective - it's my understanding of what the right definition is from other people's perspective! :P

Comment: @SamirCanning Let me work out your example in painful detail (since I am a peasant and part of the readership may be). Let $L:y=0$, $C:y=x^2$. The map $(x,y)\to (x,y/x)$ is a birational equivalence (with inverse $(x,z)\to (x,xz)$) taking $L$ to $L':z=0$ and $C$ to $C':z=x$. Clearly, $L'$ and $C'$ are lines intersecting transversally, so it would seem the intersection number (which is clearly $2$ for $L$ and $C$) cannot be a birational invariance. However, working ideal-theoretically forces out to work with $\phi^{-1}(L)=L'\cup R$ and $\phi^{-1}(C)=C'\cup R$, where $R$ is the line $x=0$. Right?

Comment: I last remember seeing it used in Partition and Analytic Rank are Equivalent over Large Fields by Alex Cohen, Guy Moshkovitz (where indeed the final goal is counting points on varieties over finite fields).

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks. That's actually a weaker version of a special case ($V_1,\dotsc,V_k$ hypersurfaces, and we count the number of zero-dimensional components of $V_1\cap \dotsc \cap V_k$) though that is already useful for plenty of things. I am now wondering about applications of the general statement (which can be read in Fulton's book and elsewhere).

Comment: Fact 7.3 in the paper I mentioned is the general case of the statement. It might be that the full power is not used but I think what's needed is greater than the special case you describe.

Comment: @WillSawin Ah, I overlooked that. Thank you!

Comment: (Why do they need Fact 7.4? It follows immediately from Fact 7.3.)